# How can I add a secondary tooltip to an image span?

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNa85/)

I made a tooltip in CSS that displays the name of en employee when you hover over their picture.

HTML

```
<span class="customToolTip" atitle="Employee" btitle="CEO"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Employee"/></span>
```

CSS

```
.customToolTip{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.customToolTip:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 135px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 1%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    content: attr(atitle);
    width: 88px;
}
```

However, I want a secondary tooltip that displays BELOW the picture with the title of the employee.

Ive tried adding a secondary class called 'customToolTip2' but this just overrides the first one and only one displays.

How do I do this?

Comment: use `.customToolTip2:hover:before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using before as in below code:

```
.customToolTip:hover:before{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: -10px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 1%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    content: attr(btitle);
    width: 88px;
}
```

Comment: Before inserts content before element, and after simple after. But when you want to use them for tooltip using also hover using after and before you can simple achieve result you wanted - display 2 tooltip